docker-compose.dcproj project showing 'incompatible' in visual studio
I have gone through several similar issue blogs on stackoverflow but still I couldn't resolve my issue:

My VS version: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current , Version 17.9.6
docker-compose.dcproj file content is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>a5eae6e3-366f-4ea4-90d4-3b259dd2f30c</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchAction>None</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerServiceUrl>{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/api-docs/rlm</DockerServiceUrl>
    <DockerServiceName>rlmservice</DockerServiceName>
    <DockerComposeProjectName>rlm_debug</DockerComposeProjectName>
    <ContainerDevelopmentMode>Regular</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.dev.yml" />
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml" />
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have installed the following items in my VS:

My control panels shows following packages of Microsoft installed:

What Am I missing and What can I do to add this project in my solution explorer so that I can build my solution or atleast make my solution run in localhost?
Thanks in advance for your time.

I recently encountered this issue. In case it's still helpful, my solution was related to not having the Component Tools installed in Visual Studio 2022. I used this post from the Visual Studio Developer Community to help resolve it.
Basically, I searched for "Component Tools" in the Visual Studio search bar, and located the "Install Component Tools" option. After that completed, I simply right clicked on the docker-compose project and clicked "Reload". I hope this helps.
